# bind_param() on a non-object when adding now() for date

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object, when I do this

```
$query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, date) VALUES (?, now())");

    $query->bind_param('s',$name);

            if( $query->execute()){
            echo 'record added';
        }
        else{ 
            echo 'not added';

        }
```

It works as soon as I remove date, but I need date too in database

```
$query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name) VALUES (?)");
    $query->bind_param('s',$name);

            if( $query->execute()){
            echo 'record added';
        }
        else{ 
            echo 'not added';

        }
```

This is updated and still not working

```
    $team ="INSERT INTO team (team_name, date) VALUES (?, now())";
    $query= $db->prepare($team);
    $query->bind_param('s',$name);

            if( $query->execute()){
            echo 'record added';
        }
        else{ 
            echo 'not added';

        }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli? Your `bind_param()` syntax is from mysqli.

Comment: i am actually using PDO

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result of `$db->prepare()` to `$team` but you are using `$query` later.

Try this:

```
$query =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name) VALUES (?)");
```

And a last advice: If `$db->prepare()` doesn't return an object it usually returns false due to a MySQL error. You have to check this error with `$db->error`. In your case it's most probably because `date` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You should avoid to use reserved words as table or column names. If you have to, escape them with backticks (`):  `date`.

Comment: ops ill just fix it n see if it wrks

Comment: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference  when i used '$query->bind_param(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
'

Comment: i also changed name date to join date not helping

Comment: add `print_r( $db->errorInfo() );` after your `prepare()` call. What's the output?

Comment: got an error saying ""  Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo() ""

Comment: Well, at least we now know that you are using mysqli, not PDO. What does `var_dump($query);` print?

Comment: i got this object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) } not added

Comment: Are you sure it is still throwing the error about calling a function on a non-object? Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: it is working: problem was i inserted duplicate name teamb again while it was already inserted once before.. thank you for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error `$team`:

```
$team =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, date) VALUES (?, now())");
```

Try

```
$query =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, `date`) VALUES (?, now())");
```

Comment: i changed it but not working still, it directly echo not added

Comment: '$team =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, date) VALUES (?, now())");
     $team->bind_param('s',$name);
     
       if( $team->execute()){
    echo 'record added';
   }
   else{ 
    echo 'not added';
    
   }   '

Answer (score 0):

$team =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, date) VALUES (?, now())");

```
$team->bind_param('s',$name);

        if( $team->execute()){
        echo 'record added';
    }
    else{ 
        echo 'not added';

    }
```

You can use this and check